# Python fairy game

Tags: python

I've attached my assignment to this post; I wrote the code and everything is perfect but one part is really bugging me. I have to mention the person with the highest score and mention their score. I tried putting it in a for loop but it's not working. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I've put the part giving me errors in comments.

```
from random import randint

def main():
    name = input("Enter a fairy's name, 'end' when done: ")
    largest_height = 0.0
    while name != "end":
        select_colour = randint(1,4)
        colour = pixieDusting(select_colour)
        height = computeHeight(colour)
        #for element in range(height+1):
            #if element>element-1:
                #largest_height = (height(element))
                #largest_name = ()
        print(name, "was dusted with", colour, "pixie dust and flew", height, "metres high.")
        name = input("Enter a fairy's name, 'end' when done: ")
    #print("The highest flight was", largest_height, "by", largest_name)

def pixieDusting(select_colour):
    select_colour = randint(1,4)
    if select_colour == 1:
        colour = "Red"
        return colour
    if select_colour == 2:
        colour = "Blue"
        return colour
    if select_colour == 3:
        colour = "Green"
        return colour
    if select_colour == 4:
        colour = "Yellow"
        return colour

def computeHeight(colour):
    if colour == "Red":
        height = randint(40, 49)
        return height
    if colour == "Blue":
        height = randint(30, 39)
        return height
    if colour == "Green":
        height = randint(20,29)
        return height
    if colour == "Yellow":
        height = randint(10, 19)
        return height

main()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's best to add the error message you've got so that it's clearer what has gone wrong in your code.

What is it that you want the code in the comments to do? Your assignment is to find the highest-flying fairy, so how can you compute this?

On each pass of your while loop, you have the variables `name` and `height` set to be the current fairy's name and height. So, you want to see if this current height is greater than what was saved as the greatest height (in the `largest_height' variable).

So your commented out code in the comments might look more like this:

- an `if` statement that checks if `height` is greater than `largest_height`
- If true, then change `largest_name` to `name`, and change `largest_height` to `height`
- If false, do nothing, and go to the next fairy.

You don't need a `for` loop because you're not iterating over anything; you're not keeping a list of the fairies to look through, or something.

Give that a go and let me know how it goes:)

Comment: I get an error saying Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not callable
Also I have tried putting it in an if statement but that didn't work. A for loop was my las resort